# Printing FAT32 file systerm information by reading device file

Tags: c, linux

I want to write a program that can print out the information of a FAT32 file systerm like Number of of sectors per cluster by reading a device file, for example, a device file called fat32.disk
How can I do this in C? should I read the file by using `fopen("fat32.disk","r")` ? 
Then how can I locate the information stored on Volume ID in fat32.disk? something like `sectors_per_cluster = 0x0D` in my script?

Comment: Try to look for a fat32 spec the rest should be easy. This here looks fine: http://wiki.osdev.org/FAT#BPB_.28BIOS_Parameter_Block.29

Comment: Maybe I should ask another question: how can I read a specific position of the file after I open a file in C?

Comment: Try to use the function [`fseek()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fseek/) with that you should be able to jump relativ or absolute to the point you desire.